# Is the word "actually" redundant in the context?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> Some psychologists believe that we can explain every decision or
> choice that an individual makes by referring to some earlier
> conditioning that the individual has undergone, so that, although the
> individual might feel free, his or her action is in fact entirely
> determined by what has happened in the past, and by genetically
> transmitted predispositions. **We cannot know for certain that this
> isn’t actually the case**.

Philosophy: The basics

I don't know the use of "actually" in the context above. Is it redundant?
Is there any difference between "this isn’t actually the case" and "this isn’t the case"?

I tried to understand the bold sentence like this: We cannot know for certain whether this is actually the case or not. Is my understanding correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Semantically might be redundant (it does not change the meaning), yet overall it's not redundant: it lends an emphasis otherwise not achieved.

As per [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/actually#collins-section):

> ***Actually***
> A parenthetic filler used to add a slight emphasis

I believe in this sentence it emphasizes that the author/speaker *indeed*, *really* does not know whether this is the case or not; additionally, they distance themselves from being an authority in determining it.

Also, there is an additional thing at play here:

Your quote, actually, is just two sentences. The first, very long, complex one is the non-bold, while the second is the very short bold one.

I believe when following this long and complex sentence, the short bold one has a chance to miss its impact — simply due to how it's off-pattern compared to the rhythm of the rest of the speech. Injecting `actually` into this short, quick sentence lends it extra volume and a variety of pattern, thus makes it more remarkable, more prominent. This should help the reader to pick up the meaning of the entire paragraph with less effort.